# Calculating week number in Excel, when Day starts on Sunday

Tags: excel-formula

The following formula works great for calculating week number using the ISO standard, meaning the first week of the year is defined as beginning on the Monday of the week in which the first Thursday of January occurs. The date is located in C2.

=INT((C2-DATE(YEAR(C2-WEEKDAY(C2-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(C2-WEEKDAY(C2-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)

How do I change the formula to the US system, where the first week of the year is defined as beginning on the Sunday of the week in which the first Wednesday of January occurs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would give a try using Excel's built in `WEEKNUM` formula. It doesn't work reliably for your US calculation, but for your ISO calc, it is pretty straightforward. You should be able to replace your formula above with the following

```
=WEEKNUM(C2,21)
```

For the US calculation, the following should work

```
=INT((C2-DATE(YEAR(C2-WEEKDAY(C2-0)+4),1,4)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(C2-WEEKDAY(C2-0)+4),1,4))+6)/7)
```

Comment: What is in $B$2, $B$3, $B$4 and $B$5?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was testing and forgot to change back. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I tested it for several years, and I get some discrepancies. 2010 starts with Friday 1 Jan, week 53, but I am getting week 52. http://www.calendar-365.com/2010-calendar.html

Comment: I don't think it should be week 53. If you take a look at the beginning of 2009, week 1 starts on 1/4/2009, week 2 on 1/11/2009. If you continue that through, then week 52 starts on 12/27/2009. I think the formula is working as it should, but let me know if I'm thinking about this incorrectly.